# Building a C/C++ program for Windows/MacOS/Linux with dependencies

Tags: c++, c, makefile, build, cross-platform

I need to build a program on Windows, MacOS and Linux which relies on multiples dependencies. I tried to limit them as much as I could but I should ended up using [WxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/), [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/), [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) and [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/).

I choose those dependencies because I must be able to:

- compute a md5 hash (openssl)
- decompress a zip archive (libarchive)
- provide a GUI (WxWidgets)
- use HTTPS (libcurl)

I am aware that this might be an overkill to import 5 libraries to *only* do those 5 things but I do not know any better solution yet. As I am writing this, I'm only using libcurl and openssl and building for Windows, MacOS and Linux is already very difficult for me.

I would like to distribute a standalone executable for each platform in addition to the source code, to build my project, I use the following Makefile :

```
CXX = g++
NAME = foo
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
CXXFLAGS = -I./inc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g 

all : $(NAME)

$(NAME) : $(OBJ) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto

clean :
    rm -rf $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

fclean : clean
    rm -rf $(NAME) test

re : fclean all

reclean : fclean all clean

.PHONY : all clean fclean re reclean
```

This worked great(even on Windows thanks to [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and [MINGW](https://www.mingw-w64.org/)) until I tried to statically linked each library to distribute a standalone binary :

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJ) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto
```

becamed

```
$(NAME) : $(OBJ) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ libcurl.a libssl.a libcrypto.a
```

On Linux(Ubuntu 22.04), I downloaded curl and openssl source codes and built them using  -static flags, copied the *.a inside my project's directory and I was done.

Now I'm trying to build curl and openssl on Windows with MSYS2, most of my attempts failed with error messages and took forever(> 30 minutes) to complete the build process. After struggling a little too much time, I finally managed to compile openssl by adding -lcrypto -lcrypt32..?

I do not think I will be able to finish this project with this "building process" as I still need to figure it out how build and link libarchive and WxWidgets. Is there anything I am missed out regarding the building process ? Should I pick others libraries ? Or It is just how it is ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: cmake exists for exactly this reason. Integrate a package manager like conan or vcpkg (manifest mode), and this should be trivial.

Comment: btw importing 5 libraries to do 5 things is by no means "overkill".

Comment: Are you mixing C and C++?  They are two distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::vector`, `std::string` and exceptions.  The C language doesn't.  Also, since C++ allows operator and function overloading, mixing with the C language can get difficult.  I highly recommend using one or the other.

Comment: I did not know about CMake and Conan, thank you. I'm still struggling to compile on Windows because it looks like CMake is using VisualStudio compiler which differs a lot from Linux/MacOS compiler(c++) but *its just* about my code and not libraries anymore so its a great improvement, I hope to get this to work soon ! Thank you again.

Comment: Just to let you know, WxWidgets and similar old classic GUI lib are going to die... the future is the Web, so, use WebView UI, WebUI.me, or any web-based UI library.

Comment: "The future is..." predictions are always  funny to read.